# Using strncat to insert values to a string

Tags: c

I need to open a file, find a "variable" given by the user and then proceed to write the line where I found it in a new file. What I tried to do was save a complete line, append `\0` once it was stored and proceed to use `strncmp` to compare it.

However, I have trouble inserting the `\0` to the line. What do I need to change in order for it to work?

```
    char line[500];
    char *finLin = "\0"; 
   
    while (i < readBytes) {
            i++;

            // Line is saved.
            while(buffer[i] != '\n' && i < readBytes){
                line[j] = buffer[i];
                i++;
                j++;
            }

            // Add '\0' to the line.
            strncat(line, finLin, 2);

            // Use strcmp to compare. If the variable is found, it is written.
            if(strncmp(line, var, n) == 0){
                write(status2, line, strlen(line));
                printf("%s \n", line);
            }

            // Reset counter.
            j = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Your string literal is not a string.  [Footnote 78 of the C11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note78) applies:  "A string literal need not be a string, because a null character may be embedded in it by a \0 escape sequence."

Comment: @AndrewHenle This is a misleading addendum, no? That footnote helps clarify the distinction between a string and a string literal, and links to [§7.1.1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.1) in order to do so. The distinction being that `"abc\0efg"` is not a *string*, because a string is a sequence *terminated* by (and including) the first null character, whereas the aforementioned literal's sequence *continues* past a null character (hence why the term "*multibyte character sequence*" is used). Regardless, the eventual resultant static array will contain a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're concatenating what is effectively a zero-length string, which does nothing. Remember, `\0` or NUL is not part of the C string, it is the *terminator* of the C string. If that isn't present, `strncat` will not operate as you expect, it will proceed to look for the end, then add nothing there, or it will terminate early if not NUL was found. In both cases the result is the same.

What you should be doing here is `line[j] = 0` to properly terminate the string after reading.

Don't think of C arrays as something you can append to, that has an intrinsic size. They have a *fixed size* and fully populated with values even of those values are uninitialized. When you "append" to a C string, you're really just writing to a specific offset in a pre-existing buffer. `strncat()` just looks for the appropriate place to append to.

Comment: Nit: I get your aim with "\0 or NUL is not part of the C string, it is the terminator of the C string." yet that sounds different than the definition "A _string_ is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character."  More like the _null character_ is part of the _string_ - the last part, just not part of the prior contiguous sequence of characters

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The terminator is part of the string, but not part of the string data per-se, it's just unusually visible as compared to things like C++ which have a hidden length field that you can basically ignore. C forces you to be aware of termination. When speaking more generally about strings, the terminator or length field is sort of ignored, but you're right that it's relevant here.

Comment: For me, in C-land, the _null character_ is part of the _string_.  In other lands, [When_in_Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_in_Rome,_do_as_the_Romans_do)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Ironically the Romans didn't have a zero.

Comment: [Roman zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Zero) eventually came along.